# Python format() to print the decimal, oct, hex, and binary values

Tags: python, binary, format, hex

I am trying to use `.format()` in python 
I wish to print

> 1 to N with space padding so that all fields take the same width as the binary value.

Below is what i have tried till now

```
n=int(input()) 
width = len("{0:b}".format(n)) 
for num in range(1,n+1):
    print ('  '.join(map(str,(num,oct(num).replace('0o',''),hex(num).replace('0x',''),bin(num).replace('0b','')))))
```

I don't know how to use the `.format()` function properly here. Kindly help

Comment: `format` is a flexible function, with multiple levels of substitution, e.g. `'{0:{padding}{width}{format}'.format(10, padding=' ', width=4, format='x')` would format the number 10 as hex padded with a space to 4 characters. Consider you need the formats `['b', 'o', 'd', 'x']` for each number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below code finds all hexadecimal,binary,octal and decimal values

```
n = int(input())
w = len("{0:b}".format(n))
for i in range(1,n+1):
  print ("{0:{width}d} {0:{width}o} {0:{width}x} {0:{width}b}".format(i, width=w))
```

Comment: For uppercase Hex, you can use X instead of x.

Answer (score 5):

```py
# the simplest one.

def print_formatted(number):
    width=len(bin(number)[2:])
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        deci=str(i)
        octa=oct(i)[2:]
        hexa=(hex(i)[2:]).upper()
        bina=bin(i)[2:]
        print(deci.rjust(width),octa.rjust(width),hexa.rjust(width),bina.rjust(width))
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Hackerrank String Formatting**

```
def print_formatted(numbers):
   w = len("{0:b}".format(numbers))
   for i in range(1,n+1):
      o=oct(i)
      h=hex(i)
      b=bin(i)
      o=o.replace("0o","")
      h=h.replace("0x","")
      b=b.replace("0b","")
      print(str(i).rjust(w),o.rjust(w),h.upper().rjust(w),b.rjust(w))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   n = int(input())
   print_formatted(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting
where the conversion flags and conversion types are described.

As an example, the part to format your number in octal with the length `width` looks like this:

```
'{0:{w}o}'.format(n, w=width)
```

This will first create a formatted string that looks like this `{0:4o}` (with width = 4) and afterwards create the final string.

Comment: Is this chaining necessary? Wouldn't `'{0:{w}o}'.format(n, w=width)` be sufficient?

Comment: @AChampion you're totally right, that works too and is simpler

Answer (score 1):

Below code print the decimal,oct,hex and binary values using format function in specifying width only

```
width = len('{:b}'.format(number))
for i in range(1,number+1):
    print(str.rjust(str(i),width),str.rjust(str(oct(i)[2:]),width),str.rjust(str(hex(i).upper()[2:]),width),str.rjust(str(bin(i)[2:]),width))
```

Comment: You could add some more explanation to what are you doing differently in your code or how does that answer the question

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_formatted(number):
    width=len(bin(number)[2:])
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        deci=str(i)
        octa=oct(i)[2:]
        hexa=(hex(i)[2:]).upper()
        bina=bin(i)[2:]
        print(deci.rjust(width),octa.rjust(width),hexa.rjust(width),bina.rjust(width))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.format()` can be used to define the width only but instead of a loop you may use a comprehension:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    width = len("{0:b}".format(n))
    return [print(str(n).rjust(width), 
            oct(n)[2:].rjust(width), 
            hex(n)[2:].upper().rjust(width), 
            bin(n)[2:].rjust(width)
            ) for n in range(1, number+1)], 
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler code..

```
def print_formatted(number):
    width=len("{:b}".format(number))
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        temp=""
        temp+=("{0:d}".format(i)).rjust(width)+" "
        temp+=("{0:o}".format(i)).rjust(width)+" "
        temp+=("{0:X}".format(i)).rjust(width)+" "
        temp+=("{0:b}".format(i)).rjust(width)
        print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def print_formatted(number):
    # your code goes here
    n = len(bin(number).split('b')[1])
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        print(str(i).rjust(n), oct(i).split('o')[1].rjust(n), hex(i).split('x')[1].upper().rjust(n), bin(i).split('b')[1].rjust(n))
```

Python string method `rjust()` returns the string right justified in a string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar (default is a space). The original string is returned if width is less than `len(s)`.